# Facebook ads campaign not displaying app installs data

Tags: android, flutter, facebook-analytics, facebook-ads, facebook-business-manager

I am regularly posting Facebook ads for my android app in playstore. My Facebook ads campaigns are not showing any data for columns like Results, Mobile App install, Cost per app install. I want to track the app installs from the ad clicks. It just shows a dash '-' line instead. I have connected my facebook ads manager with Facebook developer account and configured sdks in android app built with Flutter. I have also added objective as App Installs while starting campaign. I am using FB login for app for a year without any issue. Having this issue for sometime now. Any help would be appreciated. TIA

I have read and already followed steps from following pages:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-ads/measuring/measuring-using-facebook-analytics/

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-android

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution for this issue?